Ubuntu 22.04 LTS brokes after update
After an update yesterday, the screen shows "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." I tried many solutions, but none worked for me.
When I run apt upgrade, it returns a list of unmet dependencies and says:
ariel@ariel-pc: $ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done    
Reading state information... Done    
You might want to run 'apt -fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unnet dependencies:
gir1.2-gtk-4.0 Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.6.0) but it is not installed
g.js Depends: libg.js0g (= 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) but it is not installed
gnome-settings-daemon: Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-common (= 42.1-1ubuntu2.2) but 46.0-1ubuntul is installed  
gnone-shell: Depends: gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 (>= 42.3) but 42.0-5 is installed Depends: gir1.2-gnonedesktop-4.0 (>= 40) but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-gweather-4.0 (>= 4.1) but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-mutter-14 (>= 46.0) but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-nna4-1.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-soup-3.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-webkit-6.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gnone-shell-common (= 46.0-0ubuntu6 24.04.5) but it is not installed
Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0t64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installed
Depends: libatk1.0-0164 (>= 1.12.4) but it is not installed
Depends: libecal-2.0-3 (>= 3.45) but it is not installed
Depends: libedataserver-1.2-27t64 (>= 3.45) but it is not installed Depends: libg.js0g (>= 1.73.1) but it is not installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0164 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libgnone-desktop-4-2t64 (>= 40) but it is not installed
Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.12.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libical3t64 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libnutter-14-0 (>= 46.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0t64 (>= 0.3.10) but it is not installed
Reconnends: evolution-data-server (>= 3.45) but 3.44.4-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
Reconnends: gnone-control-center (>= 1:42) but 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.9 is installed    
gnone-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng: Depends: gir1.2-gnomeautoar-0.1 but it is not installed
gnone-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock: Depends: gnone-shell (<43) but 46.0-0ubuntu6 24.04.5 is installed
ibus-gtk4: Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.3.1) but it is not installed
libaduaita-1-0 Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.5.0) but it is not installed
libatk-urapper-java-jni: Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0164 (>= 2.18.1-2) but it is not installed
Depends: libatk1.0-0164 (>= 2.38") but it is not installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.79.0)
libgck-2-2: Depends: libglib2.0-0164 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not installed
libger-4-4: Depends: libglib2.0-0164 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not installed
libgmp10: Breaks: libgnp10:1386 (1= 2:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 2:6.3.0+dfsg-Zubuntuó is installed
libgmp10:1386: Breaks: libgmp10 (1= 2:6.3.0+dfsg-Zubuntu6) but 2:6.2.1+dfsg-Jubuntul is installed
libgnome-bg-4-1: Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.4.0) but it is not installed
libgtk-4-bin Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.6.9-ds-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
openssl Depends: libss13t64 (>= 3.0.9) but it is not installed
thunderbird-locale-en: Depends: thunderbird (>= 2:1snap1-0ubuntu3) but 1:115.16.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed thunderbird-locale-es: Depends: thunderbird (>= 2:1snap1-0ubuntu3) but 1:115.16.0 build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
xdg-desktop-portal-gnome: Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.6.0) but it is not installed
E: Unnet dependencies. Try 'apt -fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

So, I tried that, but it again returns the list of dependencies and now says:
ariel@ariel-pc: $ sudo apt -fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gir1.2-gtk-4.0 Depends: libgtk-4-1 omega = 4.6 * 0 ) but it is not installed
g.js: Depends: libg.js0g (= 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) but it is not installed
gnome-settings-daemon: Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-common (= 42.1-1ubuntu2.2) but 46.0-1ubuntul is installed
gnome-shell: Depends: gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 (>= 42.3) but 42.0-5 is installed Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-4.0 (>= 40) but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-gueather-4.0 (>= 4.1) but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-mutter-14 (>= 46.0) but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-nma4-1.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-soup-3.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gir1.2-webkit-6.0 but it is not installed
Depends: gnone-shell-connon (= 46.0-0ubuntu6 24.04.5) but it is not installed
Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0t64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installed
Depends: libatk1.0-0164 O = 1.12 * 0.4 ) but it is not installed
Depends: libecal-2.0-3 O = 3.45 ) but it is not installed
Depends: libedataserver1.2-27t64 (>= 3.45) but it is not installed
Depends: libg.js0g C >= 1.73 * 0.1 ) but it is not installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libgnone-desktop-4-2t64 (>= 40) but it is not installed
Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.12.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libical3t64 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installed
Depends: libmutter-14-0 C >= 46 ) but it is not installed
Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0t64 c >= 0.3 * 0.1 ) but it is not installed
Reconnends: evolution-data-server C >= 3.45 ) but 3.44.4-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
Recommends: gnome-control-center (but 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.9 is installed
gnone-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng: Depends: gir1.2-gnoneautoar-0.1 but it is not installed
gnone-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock: Depends: gnome-shell (<43) but 46.0-0ubuntu6 24.04.5 is installed
ibus-gtk4: Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.3.1) but it is not installed
libaduaita-1-0 Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.5.0) but it is not installed
libatk-wrapper-java-jni: Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0164 (>= 2.18.1-2") but it is not installed
Depends: libatk1.0-0164 (>= 2.38") but it is not installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.79.0)
libgck-2-2: Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not installed
libgcr-4-4: Depends: libglib2.0-0164 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not installed
libgmp10: Breaks: libgmp10:1386 (12:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 2:6.3.0-dfsg-Zubuntub is installed
libgmp10:1386: Breaks: libgmp16 (1= 2:6.3.0-dfsg-Zubuntu6) but 2:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntul is installed
libgnane-bg-4-1: Depends: libgtk-4-1 c >= 4.4 * 0 ) but it is not installed
libgtk-4-bin Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
openssl Depends: libss13t64 C > 3 * 0.9 ) but it is not installed
thunderbird-locale-en: Dependsthunderbird C > 2 :1snap1-0ubuntu3) but 1:115.16.0 build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
thunderbird-locale-es: Depends: thunderbird C >= 2 :1snap1-0ubuntu3) but 1:115.16.0 build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
xdg-desktop-portal-gnone: Depends: libgtk-4-1 o = 1 * 0 ) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver:: Resolue generated nay be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

I found many forums suggesting different solutions, such as renaming sources.list.distUpgrade back to sources.list, but now Ubuntu cannot find where to download the dependencies from.
I tried following this solution [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfpszgs6-kE&t], but I get stuck on apt --fix-broken install again.
apt update output
ariel@ariel-pc:~$ sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease

Hit:2 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease

Get:3 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]

Hit:4 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease

Fetched 126 kB in 2s (54,4 kB/s)

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

1720 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


Please edit your question to show us the complete output of sudo apt update and of sudo apt upgrade.

Looks like you uninstalled desktop or some app that entire desktop depends on. Typical of uninstalling required version  of python. If you can get to terminal, try reinstalling entire desktop. # reinstall desktop
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop then sudo  apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

@oldfred i can't remove or install anything usin apt, the output its always the same as "apt upgrade"

Take a look at the second answer here:
dpkg: "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" how to fix it?
And recovery here.
https://thelinuxcode.com/fix-broken-ubuntu-22-04-without-reinstalling/
Back up all your data before you do anything else.
All the following is AT YOUR OWN RISK.
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all [Your package name possibly xdg-desktop-portal-gnome?]
If your problem is not solved then find all the files named with your package name as a prefix and use
sudo chmod 777 filename

and then use
sudo rm filename

And then try again.
After it hopefuly works you will want to restore you system: -
apt update -m  
dpkg --configure -a
apt install -f

And finally
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Good luck.
